# how to add or store hours above 23 in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I Have a df having 2 columns ***Total Idle Time** and ***Month*** as below:

```
Total Idle Time  Month
0   0:00:00        December
1   0:02:24        December
2   26:00:00       December
3   0:53:05        December
4   28:03:39       December
```

Here the ***Total Idle Time*** column is of string format, but I want to convert it into time format as I want to add the total idle time in the month of December.

I tried converting the column to datetime as below:

```
data['Total Idle Time '] =  pd.to_datetime(data['Total Idle Time '], format='%H:%M:%S')
```

However, I got an error as follow:

```
time data '28:03:39' does not match format '%H:%M:%S' (match)
```

I thought of converting the column to int and adding them up based on the hours and minutes, but I am not successful in doing so. Is there any way to do this thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try using `pd.to_timedelta()` instead here:

```
>>> df['Idle Time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df["Idle Time"])
>>> df

   Total       Idle_Time     Month
0      0 0 days 00:00:00  December
1      1 0 days 00:02:24  December
2      2 1 days 02:00:00  December
3      3 0 days 00:53:05  December
4      4 1 days 04:03:39  December
```

You can use this to convert to numeric if you want, by scaling the results of `.total_seconds()`:

```
# in hours
>>> df['Idle Time'] = df['Idle Time'].dt.total_seconds() / 3600
>>> df

   Total  Idle_Time     Month
0      0   0.000000  December
1      1   0.040000  December
2      2  26.000000  December
3      3   0.884722  December
4      4  28.060833  December
```